# How do I find when Googlebot will visit(crawl) my pages again?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot

I implemented the **unavailable_after** tag in my pages like the below and set to unavailable after 3 days but in Google Webmaster Tools I got 404 for that page.

```
<META NAME="GOOGLEBOT" CONTENT="unavailable_after: 05-May-2014 15:00:00 EST">
```

How do I know Googlebot visit(crawl) my pages again to read this tag (or) how long Googlebot will take to crawl the pages again ? please give me a suggestion!.

Note: I set unavailable_after tag for certain content types(not whole website) with highest priority(1.0) in XML sitemap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googlebot recrawls pages with a frequency based on how popular they are and how often they have changed in the past.   CNN's home page gets crawled every few minutes.  A PageRank 0 page near the back of an unpopular blog may only get crawled monthly.

As a general rule of thumb, I allow two to three weeks for all the pages on my site to get recrawled when I make changes.

I don't believe that Googlebot actually uses the crawl priority or change date in XML sitemaps to trigger recrawls.  The only way that I know to force Google to crawl a page is to use the "Fetch as Google" feature in Webmaster Tools.   That tool has a limit of 1000 pages that have to be submitted manually one by one.

See: [How to request Google to re-crawl my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466360/how-to-request-google-to-re-crawl-my-website)

Comment: then whats the point in using the Google unavailable_after tag ?

Comment: reference http://googleblog.blogspot.ae/2007/07/robots-exclusion-protocol-now-with-even.html and  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61133/how-to-tell-google-my-content-will-expire-after-a-certain-period

Comment: You would need to add that tag well in advance.  If it is there from the time that the page is created, it could be very useful to Google.